# symfony 3.4 - vuejs, logged user data under vuejs unavailable

Tags: fosuserbundle

Like in the title. I have a problem with recieving logged user data under vuejs.

I use
 - FOS User - to login
 - Fos Rest - to api
 - Jms Serializer

This is my function to take data from database

`public function getUser()
    {
        $userId = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser('id');
        return $this->repository->FindOneBy(['id' => $userId]);
    }`

Now, when it is in form like above, console.log return an empty object, in vuejs. However, when I change $userId to 5 for example -
`$this->repository->FindOneBy(['id' => 5]);`
object is available with data.

now. I checked api addres in both cases - works. i also return a dump in both cases. everything in both cases is identical.

this is my log
when $userId

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2018:03:55:24 +0200] "GET /ekopanel2/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/greenker/user HTTP/1.1" 204 380 "http://localhost:8080/greenker" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"`

and this is when 5

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2018:03:55:34 +0200] "GET /ekopanel2/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/greenker/user HTTP/1.1" 200 895 "http://localhost:8080/greenker" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"`

i noticed that status code is different, when 5 it is 200 and working, when $userId, status code is 204, so it looks like it gets empty data.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you are logged in.

If not, $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser() would return the string "anon."

Have you tried with this :

```
    $userId = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
```

Be carefull to check if the user is logged in. Otherwise, it will throw an exception like "Call to a member function getId() on string".